# Create new variable from common colname ending before pivoting long

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

I have a data frame with multiple variables that have similar endings ("0m","6m" or "12m"). These refer to the month of the data. Some of the variables are only collected once, whilst others at 3 time points ("0m","6m" or "12m"). The data looks like this:

```
wide= data.frame(id = c(1:5),
                 agree = c("y","n","n","y","y"),
                 test1_0m = c(2,3,4,3,5),
                 test1_6m = c(3,5,2,6,7),
                 test1_12m = c(6,7,8,4,5),
                 score_0m = c(55,44,33,22,11),
                 score_6m = c(77,66,55,44,33),
                 score_12m = c(99,88,77,66,55))


> wide
  id agree test1_0m test1_6m test1_12m score_0m score_6m score_12m
1  1     y        2        3         6       55       77        99
2  2     n        3        5         7       44       66        88
3  3     n        4        2         8       33       55        77
4  4     y        3        6         4       22       44        66
5  5     y        5        7         5       11       33        55
```

I want to  `pivot_longer` to get a column `Month` which has `0m`, `6m`, or `12m` as entries, plus columns called `test1` and `score` which have the result for the corresponding person and month.

I've found a really helpful answer here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69798752/pivot-longer-for-multiple-sets-having-the-same-names-to](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

But I don't know how to specifiy the correct `regex` to get the values I want.

I've tried this, which is wrong:

```
wide%>%
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("_"), 
               names_to = c("Month", ".value"), 
               names_pattern = "(.*\\_)(.*)",
               values_drop_na = TRUE )
```

This is the output I want:

```
long
   id agree Month test1 score
1   1     y    0m     2    55
2   2     n    0m     3    44
3   3     n    0m     4    33
4   4     y    0m     3    22
5   5     y    0m     5    11
6   1     y    6m     3    77
7   2     n    6m     5    66
8   3     n    6m     2    55
9   4     y    6m     6    44
10  5     y    6m     7    33
11  1     y   12m     6    99
12  2     n   12m     7    88
13  3     n   12m     8    77
14  4     y   12m     4    66
15  5     y   12m     5    55
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just use `names_sep =`  instead of `names_pattern =` , and you need to switch the order of the names (".value", "Month").

```
wide %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("_"), 
               names_to = c(".value", "Month"), 
               names_sep = "_")
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 15 × 5
      id agree Month test1 score
   <int> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1 y     0m        2    55
 2     1 y     6m        3    77
 3     1 y     12m       6    99
 4     2 n     0m        3    44
 5     2 n     6m        5    66
 6     2 n     12m       7    88
 7     3 n     0m        4    33
 8     3 n     6m        2    55
 9     3 n     12m       8    77
10     4 y     0m        3    22
11     4 y     6m        6    44
12     4 y     12m       4    66
13     5 y     0m        5    11
14     5 y     6m        7    33
15     5 y     12m       5    55
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.value` character here it

> indicates that the corresponding component of the column name defines
> the name of the output column containing the cell values, overriding
> values_to entirely

Then you also need to define 2 capturing groups with your regex:

```
wide %>%
  pivot_longer(contains('_'), 
               names_to = c('.value', 'Month'), 
               names_pattern = '(\\w+)_(\\w+)')

# A tibble: 15 × 5
      id agree Month   test1 score
   <int> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1 y     0m        2    55
 2     1 y     6m        3    77
 3     1 y     12m       6    99
 4     2 n     0m        3    44
 5     2 n     6m        5    66
 6     2 n     12m       7    88
 7     3 n     0m        4    33
 8     3 n     6m        2    55
 9     3 n     12m       8    77
10     4 y     0m        3    22
11     4 y     6m        6    44
12     4 y     12m       4    66
13     5 y     0m        5    11
14     5 y     6m        7    33
15     5 y     12m       5    55
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
 melt(setDT(wide), measure.vars = measure(value.name, month, sep = "_"))
```

-output

```
      id  agree  month test1 score
    <int> <char> <char> <num> <num>
 1:     1      y     0m     2    55
 2:     2      n     0m     3    44
 3:     3      n     0m     4    33
 4:     4      y     0m     3    22
 5:     5      y     0m     5    11
 6:     1      y     6m     3    77
 7:     2      n     6m     5    66
 8:     3      n     6m     2    55
 9:     4      y     6m     6    44
10:     5      y     6m     7    33
11:     1      y    12m     6    99
12:     2      n    12m     7    88
13:     3      n    12m     8    77
14:     4      y    12m     4    66
15:     5      y    12m     5    55
```